# Allow float on 'input' not only on 'keypress' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, keypress

i have this code to accept valid `int` or `float` numbers.

```
$("input").on("keypress", function(event) {
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
       if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
         event.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

however, I was not able to catch user input data by `copy-paste` and `rightclick-paste` event.

I tried `$("input").on("input",...` but not working. Please see fiddle demo below.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcjncyr6/1/)

Comment: input should work, what is not working exactly?

Comment: @epascarello input event not working https://jsfiddle.net/jcjncyr6/2/

Comment: paste works for me there....

Comment: what happen if you paste this text 'this should not paste' ?

Comment: Does not paste for me... and if it has a number, it pastes in.

Comment: If you want to force a numeric only input, what about using `<input type="number" />`? It's [quite widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number). A fallback for browsers that do not support that, is either using your logic with an added `onblur` event listener. It is not the prettiest solution (users will see a flash of their pasted content, but will be replaced when they leave/blur the field), but we are talking about a small portion of users to get the latter experience ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the paste event and check numeric only after a 0ms `setTimeout` to let the value be pasted in.  You'll see a flash of whatever is pasted in so it's not an ideal solution but could be workable.

```
$("input").on("keypress", function(event) {  
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));   
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});


$("input").on("paste", function(event) {
  var element = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
     element.val(element.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
   }, 0);
});
```